# WebEdit and List Combo field Automation using UFT

Tags: hp-uft

Hi I am trying to Automate the input field for searching the equity on the website "https://www.nseindia.com/" using UFT. I am able to set value in the WebEdit field but I am not able to submit using UFT

Below is the descriptive code :

```
Set Obrowser = Browser("name:=NSE - National Stock Exchange of India Ltd\.")
Set oPage = Obrowser.Page("title:=NSE - National Stock Exchange of India Ltd\.")
oPage.WebList("html id:=QuoteSearch").Select "Equity"
oPage.WebEdit("name:=companyED","index:=0").Set "SBIN"
oPage.WebEdit("name:=companyED","index:=0").Submit
enter code here
```

[Image of the field which is highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqPBm.jpg)

Could you please help me in handling this type of input box which is shown in screenshot

Comment: Code looks like it should work.  Suggest you try a click on the field first then use `SendKeys` to send SBIN{ENTER} to the field?

Answer (score 1):

I see that when you set a value in the search field we get a list of matching results. If you click on the appropriate result the search is performed.
Instead of submit try the following:

```
oPage.WebElement("html id:=ajax_response").Link("text:=.*SBIN.*").Click
```

This assumes there is only one match (you can fine-tune it if there are more).

**Explanation:**

We first look for the list of results that fit the search term (this is in a `SPAN` with `id=ajax_response`). Then, under that, we look for the `Link` that we want to click on. In this case there's only one match so the description doesn't really matter.

Comment: I have tried with the above solution but I am getting object not found error

Comment: @jitendragupta it worked when I wrote it yesterday. Look in your report to see which object wasn't found (the `WebElement` or the `Link`) and try to figure out why it wasn't found.